# What are [HttpPost] and [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I use MVC 4, I see there are [HttpPost] and [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] at the top of some functions.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult PictureUpload(PictureModel model)
    {
     ....
    }
```

What are they???? What do this kind of expression call??? How to use them????

Comment: did you try to search these attributes.  There is a lot of docu online for both

Comment: Google is such a wonderful resource: [HttpPost](http://www.google.com/webhp?nord=1#nord=1&q=[HttpPost]+asp.net+mvc), [ValidateAntiForgeryToken](http://www.google.com/webhp?nord=1#nord=1&q=[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]+asp.net+mvc)

Comment: If I can find the answer, I will not ask here....

Answer (score 0):

Those items are attributes.

The `HttpPostAttribute` [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpunauthorizedresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
Represents an attribute that is used to restrict an action method so that the method handles only HTTP POST requests.
```

The `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`  [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
Represents an attribute that is used to prevent forgery of a request.
```

Now for the 'ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute' to function you must provide the AntiForgery token in your view using the MVC helper.

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Answer (score -1):

These are called ***attributes***. You can find detailed description on MSDN: [Attributes (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx).

To find attribute class connected with `[HttpPost]` and `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` you have to extend the attribute name with `Attribute`, so class names are [`HttpPostAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and [`ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). They are both part of `System.Web.Mvc` namespace.

> **`System.Web.Mvc.HttpPostAttribute`**
>
> Represents an attribute that is used to restrict an action method so that the method handles only HTTP POST requests.

> **`System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`**
>
> Represents an attribute that is used to prevent forgery of a request.